# Swift-How to add a parallax header like the one in Spotify?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

I was wondering if anyone knew what the best way of creating a similar tableview header effect to the one in Spotify was. I have looked at libraries such as [CSSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/tree/master/Project), but they are written in Obj-C and are for CollectionViews. What's basically got to happen is that as the user scrolls to find more tableview cells at the bottom, the header stays in the same place and the top cells start covering it. This is seen in the example section of the git page of the library above.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I would suggest you to dig into that library and use it with Swift. Creating something similar can be quite complex, and you can easily use Obj-c libraries with swift (with a bridge header). It has a lot of stars and not so many open issues = It is reliable, and maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the solution found [here](https://www.quora.com/Apple-Swift-programming-language/How-do-I-create-a-Spotify-like-interface-with-Swift-and-iOS-8)

The original example uses Obj-C but the asker's response uses Swift.  They also make use of TableViews rather than CollectionViews

Comment: Love it, its simple, short and easy to understand.

Comment: Great solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Do you still have the .zip file ? The one in that post is deleted.